# VBA Destination Variable Copy issue

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

My copy and paste code works fine when I test it IF there is already data in my destination. I need for it to work from scratch with no data for the department to begin inputing their own data. I notice that if I do not have data, it pastes over the top of my data range, or replaces data that is already there. I need it to start the first paste in cell E7 and then offset to the next row for each new set of data.

It seems to be breaking down at the Destination Variable(The whole code is posted below:

'destination variable

```
lstrow = Sheet3.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
If lstrow < 5 Then lstrow = 5
Set DstRng = Sheet3.Range("E" & lstrow).Offset(1, 0)
Set DstRng = DstRng.Resize(SrcRng.Rows.Count, SrcRng.Columns.Count)
```

**Entire Code**

```
Sub CopyCells()
'unprotect all sheets
'Unprotect_All
'dim variables
Dim DstRng As Range 'destination range
Dim SrcRng As Range 'source range
Dim Proceed As Boolean ' do we wish to proceed
Dim checkRng As Variant ' values to check
Dim i As Integer
Dim lstrow As Long

'These are mandatory fields and the error message
checkRng = Array( _
            Array("E3", "Please add the Agent Name"), _
            Array("H3", "The Evaluation Date is missing"), _
            Array("J3", "The Call Date is missing"), _
            Array("M3", "The Call ID is missing"), _
            Array("Q58", "Please score this evaluation before saving") _
            )
'Set proceed to true so this is the case unless it changes
Proceed = True

'source variable
Set SrcRng = Sheet1.Range("Eval_Data")

'destination variable
lstrow = Sheet3.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
If lstrow < 5 Then lstrow = 5
Set DstRng = Sheet3.Range("E" & lstrow).Offset(1, 0)
Set DstRng = DstRng.Resize(SrcRng.Rows.Count, SrcRng.Columns.Count)

'mandatory fields
For i = 0 To 4
    If Len(Sheet1.Range(checkRng(i)(0))) = 0 Then
        Proceed = False
        MsgBox checkRng(i)(1)
        Sheet1.Range(checkRng(i)(0)).Activate
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

' if proceed is all good then go ahead
If Proceed = True Then
'give the user a chance to exit here
    If MsgBox _
        ("You are about to finalize this Evaluation." _
        & vbCrLf & "Please check everything before you proceed", _
        vbYesNo Or vbExclamation, "Are you sure?") = vbYes Then

        'copy and paste data without selecting
        DstRng.Value = SrcRng.Value

        'add Eval number
        With Sheet1.Range("H4")
            .Value = .Value + 1
        End With

        'confirmation message
        MsgBox "The Evaluation has been saved"

        'clear the invoice
        ClearEval
    End If
End If
'reprotect
'Protect_All
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 lstrow = Sheet3.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
```

'start at the bottom and go up until you hit an occupied cell or the top of the spreadsheet

```
 If lstrow < 5 Then lstrow = 5
```

'if you hit a row less than 5 then set your pointer to 5

```
Set DstRng = Sheet3.Range("E" & lstrow).Offset(1, 0)
```

'in a blank sheet we are now at E6

```
Set DstRng = DstRng.Resize(SrcRng.Rows.Count, SrcRng.Columns.Count)
```

'This won't move the top of dstrng from E6

" I need it to start the first paste in cell E7"
Can you spot the problem?

Comment: Where I am telling it to start the 1strow

Answer (score 0):

This can be effective way to accomplish what you need:

```
With sheet3
    lstrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(7, .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row)
    Set DstRng = .Range("E" & lstrow).Resize(SrcRng.Rows.Count, SrcRng.Columns.Count)
End With
```

Comment: Please marck as answared. so every SO user will see